# How do I permanently disable PPPOE AutoDisconnect on Windows 7 X64

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, pppoe

I have a PPPOE connection and it comes up this message that the connection is been idle and it's going to auto disconnect, even when its not IDLE! I can press to stay connected BUT sometimes i'm watching an online streaming for example and the message goes background, so I get disconnected! I did uncheck the boxes for the services in internet options and the power saving configuration of the network card but the message keeps coming up!

Answer (score 1):

Open up command prompt by `Start > Run > cmd > Enter`, then enter

```
net config server /autodisconnect:-1
```

This should do it.

Comment: It did not solve the problem. I'm going to try some different drivers, see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Windows 7 Professional system and the answer Bibhas gave did not work with me either: access was denied for the command.

I solved the problem the way described on this [TechNet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/1bf6993b-0132-4252-a675-6cb3b54e80c8) but with small modifications. This solution is based on the MS knowledge base article [Q138365](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138365):

- Start Regedit van find the Autodisconnect parameter in the registry under:

  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters`
- The value range is `0` to `ffffffff` hex (minutes). To disable Autodisconnect set it to `ffffffff` hex. The value `-1` is not accepted, the value `0` makes the problem even worse. The highest possible value means that the connection will be disconnected automatically only after 8171 years.
- Restart the computer

Answer (score 0):

```
net config server /autodisconnect:-1
```

Works Fine. 
Make sure that there is no Space between `:`  and `-1`.

Comment: This should have been an edit to the other answer.